# Website Interaction

Tags: java, web

I'm new to this site (and programming in general), so don't go too rough on me haha. I learned basics of Java. I would prefer to do this in Java, I know it's not the best or probably even remotely close for this, but I'm still learning and don't wish to get confused with multiple languages just yet.

So I'm trying to create a program that can interact with a website. Basically I wish to run a program, it opens up a website and I would be able to take data from website, analyse it and interact with the page (Without using the Robot class).

I tried using: http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/
To have the browser but than I'm not quite sure how to read the data sent from the website or interact

I heard about http://docs.seleniumhq.org/
But I would like to actually have the browser opened visually

So I'm wondering how to make an application that would be be able to do both? If anyone would be able to help a newb out would be nice :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be writing a crawler which does this using Java or whatever programming language you want to use.

If you use Java - You can try HTMLUnit.

This is the best way to interact with sites.

Thanks.